# How to Get current form propety in Mobile CRM by Resco in JS Bridge?

Tags: javascript, mobile, dynamics-crm

I created a custom offline HTML and need to getProperty from current record Form. For example, when I click on an "appointment" record, I need to catch "new_address_latitude" property that is loaded in "this" form. I need a full example to get property from current record and relations.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are links from Resco JSBridge support pages. You can find many examples in reference page.

Reference page: [Reference page with examples](http://www.resco.net/mobilecrm/support/jsbridge.aspx)

Short JSBridge guide: [pdf short JSbridge guide](https://www.resco.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/JSBridge-Guide.pdf)

About this scenario, it requires to register handler what will be fired during onload of html page. How to do it, you can find in attached link to JSBridge short guide.

But code looks like this

```
window.onload = function () {
        //register this during onload
            MobileCRM.UI.EntityForm.requestObject(
            function (entityForm) {
                /// <param name="entityForm" type="MobileCRM.UI.EntityForm"/>
                // Get the MobileCRM.DynamicEntity which is being edited on this form
                var entity = entityForm.entity;
                // get specific porperty of entity object.
                var newAddresLatitude = entity.properties.new_address_latitude;

                return true;
            },
            function (err) {
                MobileCRM.bridge.alert("An error occurred: " + err);
            },null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
MobileCRM.UI.FormManager.showDetailDialog("entity", entityid, null);
```

or load the form and get the values:

```
MobileCRM.UI.EntityForm.requestObject(this.loadFormValues, MobileCRM.bridge.alert, this);
```

then get the `EntityForm object` and get the values.